# Parse a file in a C# Asp.net core project from a referenced F# project

Tags: f#, f#-data, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a design question.  I have an asp.net core full framework project.  The main project is in C#, and I have F# projects that are referenced.  What I am trying to do is parse the appsettings.json file located in the main project via one of my referenced F# projects. I am using the FSharp.Data Json provider.  I assumed I could make a dummy appsettings.json file in the F# project for the initial compile, and then when ran it would pick up the real appsettings.json file in the main project.  This does not appear to be happening. So is this procedure possible from a referenced F# project?

Comment: Couldn't you just access appsettings as you would in a regular C# core application? F# has access to all .net functionality.

Comment: I thought I might be able, to but I am unaware of the exact libraries to bring in and set up. I'm also not sure if that would be the appropriate route.

Comment: To clarify,  I know that I can access appsettings in C# and then pass that data into an F# function, but doing it that way means I have to do that over and over again.  I would rather access the data once from inside the F# project.  The only solution my novice brain can come up with alludes to the previous thought and writing a wrapper around each of my functions to accommodate the extra data.

Comment: Also to my understanding, don't you need dependency injection to get access to the appsettings, how would I do that in an external F# project?

Comment: If the F# project is a library that wants to read the configuration settings, you can create a class inside it and add `IOptions<T>` as dependency. You would do it exactly the same as you would in C#. You don't need to access the appsettings.json directly. Here's the official doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration